# How to check distance of two objects in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, figma

Hello I am very new to **Adobe Illustrator**, and I want to check how much distance or gap I am giving between objects, can anyone please tell me how to do that ?? One way I know is to use the measure tool but I am not pretty sure how to use that.

Can someone please tell me the other way to do it, for example in **Figma** we simply click the *ALT* key and hover the mouse on the other object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw a line using the **Line Tool** between the two objects. The length of that line would be the gap between your objects. If you would like illustrated step-by-step guide, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you @Siamak Ensafi :)

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

Click On "Document Setup" & select desired "Units" in which you want your distance to be measured

0 . Simply select desired objects (two, three...N )--
1 . GoTo Window - Align--
2 . Open drop menu( small bottom right icon ) " Align To"  and select "Align To Key Objects" --
3 . Enter the desired spacing in the field that changed color from Gray ( or your default color selected ) to White --
4.  Someplace next to that white field ( on the same Align tab, of course ) is the Distribute Spacing two icons --
5 . If you want a vertical space, click on the left icon or for horizontal space on the right icon--

if you are not satisfied you must have to repeat these actions in all steps since the beginning

Comment: This explains how to insert a specific amount of space, not measure space that's already there.

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  I misunderstood Q. I had the best intentions. In my opinion there is no other way than using the measure tool